# Is there a way to get a list of all skin classes in the current application?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, skinning, flex-spark

Is there a way to get a list of all the skin classes that are in the current application? I'm using Flex 4.5.1.

Here is the loop that I'm using now to get all the skins,

```
            for each (var item:Object in styleManager.typeHierarchyCache) {

                for (label in item) {

                    if (label=="spark.components.supportClasses.Skin" ||
                        label=="spark.skins.mobile.supportClasses.MobileSkin") {

                        for (label in item) {
                            name = label.substr(label.lastIndexOf(".")+1);
                            vo = new SkinObject();
                            vo.name = name;
                            vo.qualifiedName = label;
                            dictionary[label] = vo;
                        }
                        break;
                    }

                }

            }

            for each (item in dictionary) {
                array.push(item);
            }
```

The reason *why* is because I want to list all the skins in the application and then be able to apply them in real time so I can see what they look like. * I have this working but I was hoping for a better way.

Comment: Do you mean in FlashBuilder or in general?

Comment: Using AS3; I don't know of a way to get all the classes compiled into the final SWF.  Even if you could; how would you define the difference between a skin class and a non-skin class.  W/ 4.5.1 supporting ActionScript skins; you can't rely 100% on the SparkSkin class being the parent of all skins.  Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @flextras - i don't either. well, the styleManager contains a list of types in the typeHeirarchyCache. there are both ui components and skins listed in that list. i can filter the list to get the skins by checking for the base class. i'll post a code snippet in the op.

Comment: If you compile to a swc, a catalog.xml file is generated that contains all the filenames in the project. Is it an option for you to parse that file?

Comment: @RIAStar - that doesn't have anything specific to skins in it

Comment: If you would use a naming convention that all skin classes end with the word 'Skin' (like all Spark skins do) you could parse them out.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely could iterate *through all objects on the screen* and see if they're of type SparkSkin.  Something like this:

```
private function findSkins():void
{
    recurseComponent(FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication);
}

private function recurseComponent(parent:UIComponent):void
{
    var child:UIComponent;
    for(var i:uint = 0, len:uint = parent.numElements; i<len; i++)
    {
        child = parent.getElementAt(i) as UIComponent;
        if(child && child is SparkSkin)
        {
            trace("Skin Found!"); // trace whatever you need here
        }
        recurseComponent(child);
    }
}
```

But be warned that this solution is *very expensive* since it needs to iterate through all objects on the screen, which can go into several thousands.  However, I really don't see what's the purpose of this and would definitely not recommend it other than for debugging/testing purposes.

Edit:  Also, this will only work for skins on the display list.  Skins mentioned in CSS will not be recognized and I'm fairly sure there's no way of figuring that out short of going through all the css and see if there's a `skinClass` property.  But then it won't catch any default skins or skins set in actionscript or inline mxml.

Comment: Right. The code you posted will only go through the display list. The code I posted gets all the skins. It's just kludgy and doesn't give me what I'm looking for without a lot of other work.

Comment: The style manager wouldn't give you all the skins.  Only the ones specified in the css *or* the ones inline that have already been loaded.  The ones that are inline and not loaded will probably not show.  Again, don't see the purpose of this and shouldn't be doing this in the first place.

Comment: Thanks JAX and everyone. I'm putting this on hold for now.